# What is the understood subject of the subordinate clause "to address the issue this fall" in these sentences?

Tags: infinitive-clauses, parsing

What is the understood subject of the subordinate clauses in bold below?

> 1. The White House framed the announcement from the world’s two largest  polluters ahead of a landmark U.N. conference **to address the issue this fall**.
> 2. The White House framed the announcement from the world’s two largest polluters as move to position the countries in the fight against climate change ahead of a landmark U.N. conference **to address the issue this fall**.

In other words, in each of these sentences, who or what would "address the issue this fall"?

How can we figure this out?  And is there a difference between the two examples?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: It's the **White House**. Read it this way - White House framed the announcement [from the world's two largest polluters (ahead of a landmark UN conference)] to address the issue this fall.

Comment: I edited the question. plz review

Comment: In any case, it's the White House. It framed the announcement from *wherever* for *whatever* purpose ahead of *any event*... change in any of them won't alter the *subject* there. Who framed the announcement? It's the White House. UN Conference is just **an event** there. Had it been the UN Conference, it'd have been - *'UN conference **to** address the issue this fall **as** The White House framed....'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements are syntactically ambiguous.

> 1. The White House framed the announcement from the world's two largest polluters ahead of [*a landmark U.N. conference to address the issue this fall*].
> 2. *The White House framed the announcement* [from the world's two largest polluters ahead of a landmark U.N. conference] *to address the issue this fall*.
> 3. The White House framed the announcement from the world’s two largest polluters as move to position the countries in the fight against climate change ahead of [*a landmark U.N. conference to address the issue this fall*].
> 4. *The White House framed the announcement* [from the world’s two largest polluters as move to position the countries in the fight against climate change ahead of a landmark U.N. conference] *to address the issue this fall*.

In 1 and 3, *a landmark U.N. conference* is addressing the issue this fall.

In 2 and 4, it is *the White House*.

However, I would assert that **it is likely to be the U.N. Conference that addresses the issue in both cases** (1 and 3) because there's no causal link between the White House framing the announcements and then addressing the issue this fall.

Consider:

> The White House framed the announcement to address the issue this fall.

At the very least, something like this is... unidiomatic, unless you were saying it in response to a question like "Who framed the announcement?" or "Why did the White House frame the announcement?"

Comment: +1.  "to address" could be changed to "which will address".